# API time parameter automation

Tags: python, json, api

I have an API this API is having a time parameter from ,to in order to return my json file , this time has this form for example 'Wed May 12 2021' not the classical form '21/05/2021' i was requested to create an app that increment each day an get the data and store it in the database so i have trouble with this date form 'Day Month DD YYYY' :

params = (
('fromDate', 'Wed May 12 2021'),
('toDate', 'Tue May 18 2021'),
)

There is no way to automate this API to increment the time parameters ?
ps : using python as programming language

Comment: I didn't understood your question clearly, can you please explain little more? If possible with example?

Comment: I have an API this API is having a time parameter from ,to in order to return my json file , this time has this form  for example 'Wed May 12 2021'  not the classical form '21/05/2021' i was requested  to create an app that increment each day an get the data and store it in the database so i have trouble with this date form 'Day Month DD YYYY'

Comment: I had gave an answer but please add that detail in question rather then in comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! Here's what you can try, you can use `datetime` module to generate the dates and `timedelta` function add days in your date :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date

format="%a %b %d %Y"

# Today's date
dt=date.today()
print(dt)

# If you want to start from some date
dt=datetime.strptime("Wed May 12 2021",format)
print(dt)

fromdate=datetime.strftime(dt,format)
print(fromdate)

# Day to add in dt
add=6

newdate=dt+timedelta(days=add) # There are other parameters like days, weeks...
print(newdate)

formatted=datetime.strftime(newdate,format)
print(formatted)
```

Output for me is :

```
2021-08-03            dt
2021-05-12 00:00:00   dt
Wed May 12 2021       fromdate
2021-05-18 00:00:00   newdate
Tue May 18 2021       formatted
```

Variable names are themself clear what the mean. You can play with it, and learn little more and apply to your actually issue.

Comment: Thanks dear actually it is working really fine